# Delete all regular rows of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have this button that's supposed to delete all the rows inside a table except for the header. As of now, it loops through the table to delete all its row, but it never deletes all of it. In my original code, it's not included in here, I can browse through different tables and I want to be able to delete all of its content, regardless of number of row, using the same button. Coz I also try the button on other tables and it always does not delete all he items.

```js
let mealObj = {
  menu1: {
    menuName: "Steak",
    ingr1: {
      name: "Butter",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "2",
      amountType: "tbsp",
      cal: "10",
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Parsley",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "1",
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Garlic",
      ingrType: "vegetable",
      amount: "1/2",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Soy Sauce",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/4",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "20",
    },
    ingr5: {
      name: "Beef",
      ingrType: "meat",
      amount: "3/4",
      amountType: "lbs",
      cal: "200",
    },
    ingr6: {
      name: "Salt",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "0",
    },
    ingr7: {
      name: "Pepper",
      ingrType: "other",
      amount: "1/8",
      amountType: "tsp",
      cal: "2",
    },
  },
}

let ingrTable = document.getElementById("ingr-table");
objToTable(mealObj);

function objToTable(ingrList) {
let totalRowLength = ingrTable.rows.length;
  for (let i in ingrList) {
    for (let k in ingrList[i]) {
      if (ingrList[i][k].name !== undefined) {
          let tableAmount = document.createElement("INPUT");
          tableAmount.setAttribute("type", "number");
          tableAmount.id = "table-amount";
          let tableCalNum = document.createElement("INPUT");
          tableCalNum.setAttribute("type", "number");
          tableCalNum.id = "table-cal";

          let row = ingrTable.insertRow(totalRowLength);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          cell1.innerHTML = ingrList[i][k].name;
          cell2.appendChild(tableAmount);
          tableAmount.value = eval(ingrList[i][k].amount);
          cell3.innerHTML = ingrList[i][k].amountType;
          cell4.appendChild(tableCalNum);
          tableCalNum.value = ingrList[i][k].cal;
      }
    }
  }
}

let button = document.getElementById("button");
let deleteBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";
button.appendChild(deleteBtn);

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < ingrTable.rows.length; i++) {
    ingrTable.deleteRow(i + 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
<table id="ingr-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Ingredient</th>
            <th colspan="2">Amount</th>
            <th>Calorie</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you remove row 1, row 2 becomes the new row 1 and you move to the next row, deleting row 2 (which was the original row 3).

One way to solve this is to start by removing the last row and work back to the beginning

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (let i = ingrTable.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    ingrTable.deleteRow(i);
  }
});
```

An alternative, faster method is to replace the html with the headers only instead of removing all rows:

```js
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  ingrTable.innerHTML = ingrTable.rows[0].innerHTML
});
```